# Retrieving an element of a balanced binary tree in Haskell

Tags: haskell, tree, indexing

Assuming I have a custom tree datatype of the following form:

```
data BalTree a = Leaf | Node Integer (BalTree a) a (BalTree a) deriving (Eq, Show, Read)
```

and creating a new tree of size 10, I'll get this:

```
Node 10 (Node 5 (Node 2 (Node 1 Leaf 'Z' Leaf) 'Z' Leaf)
                 'Z'
                (Node 2 (Node 1 Leaf 'Z' Leaf) 'Z' Leaf))
'Z'
        (Node 4 (Node 2 (Node 1 Leaf 'Z' Leaf) 'Z' Leaf)
                 'Z'
                 (Node 1 Leaf 'Z' Leaf))
```

How do I retrieve an element in in-order transversal when given an index?

My attempt:

```
ind Leaf pos            = Nothing
ind tree@(Node n lt x rt) pos
    | pos < 0           = Nothing
    | pos > treeSize-1  = Nothing
    | pos < hTreeSize   = ind lt pos
    | pos == hTreeSize  = Just x
    | pos > hTreeSize   = ind rt (pos - hTreeSize)
    where treeSize = size tree
          hTreeSize = treeSize `div` 2
```

I'm not exactly sure if this is in-order transversal and it doesn't return the correct result.

Comment: What's wrong with your attempt?

Comment: btw, concrete type names (as opposed to variables) in Haskell must be capitalized.  So `BalTree` not `balTree`.

Comment: Sorrry guys! I'm trying to retrieve an element at a given index and not the first element. Dave: I have a feeling that I'm not doing in-order transversal at all, it doesn't return the correct result. luqui: Sorry, it was a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We want to get the nth value stored in a binary tree in an in-order walk.  We know the number of values stored in each tree rooted at each node (the `Integer` parameter of `Node`).

```
data BalTree a = Leaf
               | Node Integer (BalTree a) a (BalTree a)

size :: BalTree a -> Integer
size Leaf              = 0
size (Node size _ _ _) = size

nthInOrder :: BalTree a -> Integer -> Maybe a
nthInOrder Leaf _ =
    Nothing
nthInOrder (Node _ left x right) n
    | leftSize == n - 1 = Just x
    | n <= leftSize     = nthInOrder left n
    | otherwise         = nthInOrder right (n - leftSize - 1)
  where
    leftSize  = size left
```

The idea is this: suppose we're at node `A` and want the `n`th value:

```
  A
 / \
B   C
```

If `B` holds `n-1` values, then the `n`th value is that of `A`.  If `B` holds more or equal than `n` values, then we can ignore the rest of the tree and search only `B`; so we just recurse into it.  Otherwise, we should be looking for the value in `C`, so we recurse into it; in this case, we also need to update the `n` to reflect that there are some values in `B`, and 1 value in `A`.

In the worst case, this algorithm walks down to a `Leaf`, so, the complexity is `O(depth of tree)`.  If the tree is balanced, the complexity is `O(log2(size of tree))`.

Comment: Sooooo sorry. I'm trying to retrieve some random element when I'm given an index. Sorry for the typo.